# Nest.js & Jest: best practices for unit testing. Arranging data, mocking responses

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

To better undestand my questions, let's say I have a simple `create` method in my `UsersService` which creates a user, stores in DB, and returns created user. The method takes an object with properties such as *email, firstName, lastName, age, etc*. It returns a created user with extended fields such as *id, createdAt, updatedAt*, etc. (directly from `userRepository.create()`). And when it comes to constructing objects for Arrange or responses from Act, in some scenarios it significantly increases the length of the test case.

And my questions are the following:

1. **Arrange: Full User Object or Partial?**
   In the Arrange phase, should I define the whole user object and pass it to the create method, or is it sufficient to prepare only a subset (e.g., just the email)? Since the goal is to assert if the data passed to `userRepository.create()` matches the incoming data in `usersService.create()`, is it necessary to specify all fields in the Arrange phase?
   Additionally, should I test what data was passed to `userRepository.create()`?
2. **Act: Mocking Response**.
   Considering that the response from `userRepository.create()` is being mocked, should I mock the entire response object or is it enough to assert if the expected data, returned as a result, matches with the data returned from `usersService.create()`?

I've looked into *Object Mother* or *Data Builder* patterns. However, I couldn't find their usage in real Node.js projects, as well as other factory implementations. As a beginner, I'm curious to know if using these patterns is a common and recommended practice, and in what cases.